# dovecot post-login variables get email user

Tags: bash, variables, dovecot

I have been able to successfully use the script provide by dovecot.org for executing actions post IMAP login.  That script is generously provided here: http://wiki2.dovecot.org/PostLoginScripting

However, I can find no way to grab the actual email username (not unix username) that is logging into the IMAP account for use in an email to them about their account.

Is this possible or am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Answer (score 0):

We have used PostLoginScripting to query our ldap database (via bash script). If you have an ldap (or sql etc.) database holding your user information then you should be able to retrieve their email from that.
Apologies for posting this as an "answer" I don't have enough points to ask for more info (if you have a user db with email addresses) in a comment ;-)